# Select a custom DOM with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code in my chrome extension:

```
$.get("https://www.youtube.com/", function (response) {
    let doc1 = new DOMParser().parseFromString(response, "text/html")
    $("a:contains(NEW best video)")
});
```

How can I apply the :contains selector to the doc1 document? Currently jquery searches through my active chrome tab DOM (I have a chrome extension)

Comment: have you tried this?
https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/

Comment: This answer doens'nt solve my problem unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply the `:contains` selector to the doc1 document like this:

```
 let link = $(doc1).find("a:contains('NEW best video')").attr("href");
```

Note that the `get()` request to Youtube might not work for you because of [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS). To resolve this issue you can e.g. use [Cors Anywhere](https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/):

```
 $.get("https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/www.youtube.com/", function(response) {
    let doc1 = new DOMParser().parseFromString(response, "text/html");
    let link = $(doc1).find("a:contains('NEW best video')").attr("href");
    console.log($(this).attr("href")); 
 });
```